# Advantages/Disadvantages of adaptive contexual arithmetic coding

Tags: arithmetic, data-compression, huffman-coding

What are the advantages and drawbacks of considering ever longer block lengths or context lengths, if one was to work with estimated probabilities(measuring on the fly: aka "adaptive") rather than probability distribution that was measured offline(static).

I have thought of the following advantages

- Lesser compression as even though the context is taken into account the probability distribution of the source is not accurate, particularly for smaller n.
- Reduces the need to send the uncompressed dictionary of probabilities.
- For an nth order contextual model we will need to store $|X|^{n+1}$  ($|X| =$ alphabet size)worth of memory space to store and send the contextual data for the static model. However, this is not needed in adaptive coding. As the context length increases, this advantage plays a more important role.

For drawbacks

- More susceptible to corruption.
- Larger context length implies more conditional probability to update which may mean that the estimated distribution will take more time to approach the true distribution.